Spring-data-jpa Entity and Spring-data-solr document at the same time
I need a collection of entities in a classic relational database that I need to perform queries on, but some times I will need advanced and fast full text search.
I first tried to implement my search by myself but realized that I was basically replicating the same thing as Apache lucene and in extension elastic search, opensearch and apache solr already have but way slower.
Now I need to ensure that my database table and my solr collection are in sync. It would be great if I wasn't required to manually any the collection on database write.
I tried slapping solr annotations next to the jpa annotations but that did not lead to an in sync collection, but to an empty one.
So where did I go wrong? What do I need to do to getto my goal?
I will address a few comments I'm expecting in advance:
Q: Why don't you ditch the database and only use solr?
A: the database is connected to other legacy tooling that I will gradually replace over the next 10 years.
Q: Why solr? Elastic search is way better.
A: No particular reason. I just liked solr in a past project and it will do anything I need.
Q: Why bother with solr? Use xyz database and build a full text index.
A: I will need a search index anyways. I will sync a Minio bucket to a solr index to search pdfs anyways. It will be simpler if you have all your searches in one place instead of two.
Q: There is a plugin for hibernate that uses lucene. So why don't you use that?
A: I'm going to ingest documents too, so I will get a solr instance anyways and running two search indexes is kinda pointless.
